# Inconsistent single-word DNS resolution in OS X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

DNS resolution appears to be inconsistent across OS X for no reason I can fathom.

```
$ ping example
PING example.co.uk (80.94.32.224): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 80.94.32.224: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=62.077 ms
```

Yet:

```
$ nslookup example
Server:     10.20.20.1
Address:    10.20.20.1#53

** server can't find example: NXDOMAIN
```

http://example/ resolves in Firefox, yet:

```
$ dig example
```

fails. I am pointing at my router's default DNS (10.20.20.1, as above). Pointing to other DNS servers does not appear to alter the above behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if your search domain is set. I just tried it (with my search domain set); ping and nslookup work. As does Safari and Firefox.

However, dig does not by default on MacOS X 10.6 use the search domain. To do that do:

```
dig +search example
```

And that will work correctly

Comment: I'm reasonably sure there's an issue with search domains in Snow Leopard. Firefox, Chrome, and Safari all have issues with URLs like http://intranet/ post-SL-upgrade for me. SL is the only variable, and the others who've upgraded @ work report the same thing. It's consistently inconsistent, too - some domains work, some don't, and the ones that do or don't are the same on different computers.

Comment: Have accepted this solution, as manually setting the search domain caused the problem to disappear. This is the case even when the manually-set domain is identical to that already being set by the router!

Answer (score 0):

Did you just upgraded to snow leopard? I had very similar issues. Resolved by removing all references to saved networks in the network preferences + login/keychain databases. Basically, you have to reset your entire name resolving subsystem.

Answer (score -2):

The host is resolved via files or via other name service. See if it is in hosts. If not check 
`/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

```
grep example.com /etc/hosts
grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
```